# Системы сборки для Java

Tags: java, maven, gradle, ant

Я не совсем понимаю как работает Intellij Idea и как она собирает мою программу. Можно краткий инструктаж в системы сборки и для чего они нужны?
Ещё бы хорошо, если была бы инфа неустаревшая.

Comment: А вы для начала попробуйте разработать небольшую программу (типа "Hello world") и собрать проект вручную без IDE. Крайне рекомендую так сделать. Вам это поможет разобраться.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR**, к сожалению, не получилось.

Система сборки – это программное обеспечение, обеспечивающее **автоматизацию** сборки проекта. Основное отличие от IDE в том, что конфигурационный файл для системы сборки вы описываете в текстовом виде. Как следствие, быстрее можете начать проект, за счет того, что что все типовые задачи заключаются в копировании уже готовых сниппетов. Это гораздо быстрее, более гибко, мобильно, и, главное,  читаемо, чем вводить то же самое через UI диалоги IDE.

Как в общих чертах работает ваша *IDE*:

- Когда вы создаете проект, то *IDE* определяет некоторые source каталоги, в которых находятся исходные файлы вашего проекта. При запуске проекта эти файлы будут скомпилированы и переместятся в  целевую директорию. Все это, как правило, легко меняется. Можно назначить дополнительные source каталоги, в которых IDE будет осуществлять поиск исходных файлов или поменять целевую директорию;
- Если ваш проект использует библиотеки, то вы скачиваете их, складываете в определенную директорию, и подключаете их как зависимости вашего проекта. Таким образом IDE оповещается о том, что при запуске проекта, эти *JAR-файлы* будут находиться в `classpath`, она сама подставит их в ключ `java –cp` и начнет предоставлять типы и методы этих библиотек в автодополнении, и делать другие удобные вещи, для которых и предназначены *IDE*;
- Проекту назначается соответствующая *JDK*, компилятор которой и будет компилировать классы;
- Могут назначаться некоторые дополнительные опции, такие как переменные окружения, аргументы *JVM* и прочее;
- IDE также может выполнять определенные задачи. Например, не только положить собранный проект в каталог сборки, или запустить его, но задеплоить его на удаленный сервер;

Настройки проекта IDE сохраняет в своем внутреннем формате, и складывает в виде файлов, иногда и дополнительных каталогов в директории проекта. Вся эта логика работает через UI диалоги, которые зачастую не очевидны и плохо описаны.

Очевидные недостатки, которые из этого следуют:

- если в проекте несколько участников, они все должны использовать одну и ту же IDE и синхронизировать настройки при каждом изменении;
- тыкать мышкой в кучу разных диалогов долго и неудобно;

Кроме того, если проект большой, его нужно каким-то образом поделить на модули, а также объявить какой модуль от какого зависит. Машина разработчика 
- не единственное место где нужно запускать проект - нужны конфигурации проекта для запуска в разных средах: разработка и продакшн, как минимум. Перед сборкой проекта также необходимо запустить интеграционные и юнит- тесты (иногда очень много), чтобы убедиться в отсутствии багов.

Первым для автоматизации этих задач появился Ant. Это аналог [make-файла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make), а по сути набор скриптов (которые называются tasks). *Ant* – это пример императивного стиля описания сборки проекта. Вы описываете некое действие, например, скомпилировать файлы в директории проекта:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.classes}"
    <classpath refid="libs.dir"/>
</javac>
```

.. потом , скопировать их рабочую директорию

```
<copy todir="${build.classes}">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.*" excludes="**/*.java"/>
</copy>
```

[Все примеры из вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant).

И вот из таких маленьких кирпичиков, поэтапно собираете весь сценарий сборки проекта. А точнее, несколько сценариев для разных целей. Написав единожды хороший универсальный сценарий, можно копировать его в последующие проекты.

Удобно в *Ant* то, что вы имеете полный и наглядный контроль над сборкой проекта, а неудобно что вы описываете огромное количество очевидных задач, и по прежнему управляете зависимостями проекта вручную (существует возможность [подключить Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) для управления зависимостями).

Если вы хотите именно пошагового понимания, что делает *IDE* за ширмой - соберите проект с помощью *Ant*.

---

Правда жизни состоит в том, что большие проекты используют большое число библиотек, причем библиотека A, от которой зависит ваш проект, может в свою очередь зависеть еще от десяти других, и из этих десяти, половина будет пересекаться с другими зависимостями, от которых зависят ваши библиотеки, включенные в ваш проект :)

На смену Ant пришел Maven, который не такой гибкий, но значительно сокращает объем рутинной работы.  Основные особенности:

- Конфигурация *Maven* - это один файл `pom.xml`;
- Из коробки поддерживаются различные типы сборки: *JAR*, *WAR*, *EAR*;
- Введена [стандартная структура каталогов для проекта.](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) Это сделано для того, чтобы по умолчанию вам не нужно было объяснять системе сборки, где лежат исходные файлы, ресурсы и куда их нужно переместить после компиляции;
- Цикл сборки разбит на phases (фазы). [Каждая фаза включает в себя определенный стандартный сценарий](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings), который называется goal (цель) .  Упрощенно, вы указываете **до** какой фазы нужно выполнить проект (например, только скомпилировать), и выполняется набор сценариев связанных указанной и предыдущими фазами *build lifecycle*. Дополнительные сценарии реализуются через плагины к *Maven*;
- Поддерживается модульная архитектура проекта. Можно объявлять зависимости между модулями;
- Поддерживаются профили. Это возможность, которая позволяется выполнять сборку проекта  для различных окружений (машин) по-разному. Например, в профиле для разработки приложения определяются настройки и плагины, которых нет в профиле для продакшена, и наоборот. Т.е. можно, например, иметь разные настройки для подключения к базе данных для рабочей машины и сервера, где будет разворачиваться приложения. Или добавить профиль для развертывания среды окружения, который содержит только плагины и скрипты, которые подготовят ваше рабочее место при переезде с места на место. Название профиля передается как опция (ключ `-P`) к сборке проекта;
- Для централизованного хранения библиотек введен [центральный репозиторий](http://search.maven.org/). Все популярные библиотеки публикуются и периодически обновляются в центральном репозитории. Каждая библиотека уникально идентифицируется по параметрам: **groupId**, **artifactId**, **version**. Вам не нужно скачивать зависимости и хранить их где-то вместе с проектом, они объявляются декларативно в теге `dependency` и скачиваются автоматически при сборке проекта.

*Maven* выполняет автоматическое разрешение зависимостей (так называются библиотеки, от которых зависит ваше приложение). Таким образом, например, если библиотека *A* зависит от библиотеки *C*, и библиотека *B* зависит от библиотеки *C*, но эти *C* – разных версий, *Maven* автоматически включит в проект только последнюю версию *C* (иногда это минус, но все настаивается). Также просто, например, проверить не появились ли новые версии для библиотек, входящих в состав проекта:

`mvn versions:display-dependency-updates`

Поскольку зависимости выкачиваются автоматически, очень удобно делить проект между участниками команды. Предположите, как-бы вы управляли большим числом зависимостей вручную;

- *Maven* поддерживает архетипы. Это предопределенная структура проекта (шаблон) для быстрого начала разработки приложения. При создании проекта вы можете указать архетип, и вот уже есть некая начальная заготовка. Естественно, можно создавать собственные.

Для *Maven* есть огромное число полезных плагинов. Основной недостаток, которым ему обычно пеняют, вытекает из его преимуществ. Декларативный стиль описания задач не позволяет так же просто “подшаманить” в определенных случаях, как это делает *Ant*. Но и это обычно  решается через через различные плагины. Например, задачм *Ant* можно запускать из *Maven* через [antrun-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

Нужно отметить, что когда вы работаете с *Maven* проектом в *IDE*, настройки извлекаются именно из *Maven*. Например, через `compiler-plugin` проекту указывается версия *JDK*:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Все *IDE* на сегодняшний момент хорошо хорошо работают с *Maven* - можно использовать любую. *UI* диалог *IDE* для запуска *Maven* проекта - это обертка, при желании вы можете работать в ним из командной строки.

За *Gradle* не скажу, потому что игрался, но вплотную не использовал.

**Резюме:** если вы учитесь или делаете тестовый проект без зависимостей на час - *IDE* нормальный вариант - хотя сейчас все туториалы тоже пишутся под *Maven* или *Gradle*. Для остального - система сборки.

---

**Обновление:**

Как вам правильно указал @Arsenicum, проект можно собрать и без участия *IDE* и систем сборки. *JDK (Java Development Kit)*, которое необходимо для разработки, как раз и состоит из *виртуальной Java машины (JRE)* - это среда исполнения или рантайм, и *Development Tools* - это инструменты среды разработки.

*Development Tools* - это набор, в основном, консольных утилит. Они находятся в директории `$JAVA_HOME/bin`. [Полный список тут](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/). Умение **напрямую** работать с утилитами из набора **Basic Tools** (особенно *jar*, *java*, *javac*, *javadoc*), несомненно поможет лучше ориентироваться в вопросах запуска и сборки *Java* приложений.

Comment: Хороший развернутый ответ. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Отлично расписано, но есть пара замечаний: 1) _JRE_ - это исполнительная среда Java, которая уже как раз включает виртуальную машину Java (_JVM_) + библиотеки Java классов. (к слову о `виртуальной Java машины (JRE)`) 2) Вы смешиваете _UI (User Interface)_ с _UX (User Experience)_ (к слову о `тыкать мышкой в кучу разных диалогов долго и неудобно;` - интерфейс не делает _IDE_ удобной/неудобной - он может сделать её лишь красивой/некрасивой) 3) Чувствуется предвзятость по отношению к _Maven_ :)

Answer (score 4):

**Главная особенность**, когда вы используете **ant, gradle или maven**, что сборка вашего продукта - это тоже **код** и вы им управляете как кодом и он хранится вместе с исходниками вашей программы.

Т.б. для воспроизведения всех шагов по сборке проекта достаточно установить систему сборки и получить код вашего проекта (git, svn) - после этого одна команда и ваш проект собран, а иногда даже и запущен, а еще лучше если протестирован и задеплоин.

Есть всегда базовые стандартные примеры, которые вы можете использовать для начала работы с этими системами (в мавен - это архитип, в gradle - это темплейты). Возмите простой пример консольного приложения и поиграйте с ним. Попробуйте пройти все главные шаги любого приложения - сборка, тест, деплой.
Для веб приложений этот сценарий просто чуть шире и состоит из нескольких тестов и деплоев.

Отсюда вывод - используйте всегда gradle ) и посмотрите еще в сторону Docker и такого понятия, как инфраструктура как код - это просто дальнейшее развитие этой идеи - все хранить в виде кода.